# Unordered Sub-Productions in ANTLR4

Tags: antlr4

I want to specify a production in ANTLR where the order of its sub-productions does not matter. Note that I want each of the sub-productions to occur once. The brute force way to accomplish this would look something like this:

```
grammar Foo;

r : (A B) | (B A) ;

A : 'a' ;
B : 'b' ;
```

As more sub-productions are added, the number of permutations increases...  n!/(n-k)!

```
grammar Foo2;

r : (A B C) | (A C B) | (B A C) | (B C A) | (C A B) | (C B A) ;

A : 'a' ;
B : 'b' ;
C : 'c' ;
```

Obviously the above solution is not practical. Is there a construct in ANTLR which describes permutations like this in a more concise way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is no way to describe a permutation in a production in ANTLR. You will need to match `A`, `B` or `C` three times and then use a [listener](https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR4/Parse+Tree+Listeners) to check if all three tokens have been matched exactly one time.

You could do it inside your grammar using custom code and a predicate, but that would make your grammar very hard to read: best do this with a listener.